# How to track changes in rows/lines of data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe
df:

```
df=data.frame(ID=c(123100,123200,123300,123400,123500),"2014"=c(1,1,1,2,3),"2015"=c(1,1,1,2,3),"2016"=c(2,1,1,2,1), "2017"=c(2,1,1,2,1), "2018"=c(2,3,1,2,1) )
```

Now, I want to find out, for which ID the data has changed in which year. So for example, in 2016 ID 123100 has changed from 1 to 2. I would like to add new columns for change (1 = change, 0 = no change), year of change, old value (1,2 or 3) and new value (1,2,3).

In the end it should look like this:

```
df_final=data.frame(ID=c(123100,123200,123300,123400,123500),"2014"=c(1,1,1,2,3),"2015"=c(1,1,1,2,3),"2016"=c(2,1,1,2,1), "2017"=c(2,1,1,2,1), "2018"=c(2,3,1,2,1), "change"=c(1,1,0,0,1),
          "year"=c(2016, 2018, 0, 0, 2016), "before"=c(1,1,0,0,3), "after"=c(2, 3, 0, 0, 1))
```

I couldn't find any satisfying solution on here, so I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an optional `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# join resume df to current df
dplyr::left_join(df, 
                 # make df long to build groupings by ID
                 tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -ID) %>% 
                     dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
                     # order just to be sure
                     dplyr::arrange(ID, name) %>%
                     # generate year number, before and after values
                     dplyr::mutate(year = readr::parse_number(name),
                                   before = lag(value), 
                                   # if there is no after value use current value
                                   after = ifelse(is.na(lead(value)), value, lead(value))) %>%
                     # filter where preceding uneven current
                     dplyr::filter(before != value) %>%
                     # unselect obsolete columns
                     dplyr::select(-name, -value),               
                 by = "ID") %>%
    # fill up empty fields with zeros
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(year:after, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))

      ID X2014 X2015 X2016 X2017 X2018 year before after
1 123100     1     1     2     2     2 2016      1     2
2 123200     1     1     1     1     3 2018      1     3
3 123300     1     1     1     1     1    0      0     0
4 123400     2     2     2     2     2    0      0     0
5 123500     3     3     1     1     1 2016      3     1
```

another possibility to solve the task within the `tidyverse` is to work `row-wise`:

```
dplyr::rowwise(df) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(year = readr::parse_number(names(.)[stringr::str_detect(names(.), pattern = "^X")][c(0, diff(dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x")))) != 0][1]),
                  before = dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x"))[dplyr::lead(c(0, diff(dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x")))) != 0, default = FALSE)][1],
                  after = dplyr::coalesce(dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x"))[dplyr::lag(c(0, diff(dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x")))) != 0, default = FALSE)][1],
                                          dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x"))[c(0, diff(dplyr::c_across(dplyr::starts_with("x")))) != 0][1])) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(year:after, ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))

      ID X2014 X2015 X2016 X2017 X2018  year before after
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 123100     1     1     2     2     2  2016      1     2
2 123200     1     1     1     1     3  2018      1     3
3 123300     1     1     1     1     1     0      0     0
4 123400     2     2     2     2     2     0      0     0
5 123500     3     3     1     1     1  2016      3     1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the first tidyverse approach worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R method.

It may be best to have the IDs with no change as `NA`. If you really want zeroes, just change `c(NA, NA, NA)` in the following code to `c(0, 0, 0)`

Note that in your example data frames, if you run the code as-is, the column names for each year all start with an "x" - you can prevent this by adding the `check.names = FALSE` argument to the `data.frame` function.

```r
cbind(df, setNames(as.data.frame(t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
  y <- which(diff(x) != 0) 
  if(length(y)) c(as.numeric(names(y)), x[y], x[y+1])
  else c(NA, NA, NA)
}))), c("Year", "Before", "After")))
#>       ID 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 Year Before After
#> 1 123100    1    1    2    2    2 2016      1     2
#> 2 123200    1    1    1    1    3 2018      1     3
#> 3 123300    1    1    1    1    1   NA     NA    NA
#> 4 123400    2    2    2    2    2   NA     NA    NA
#> 5 123500    3    3    1    1    1 2016      3     1
```

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123100, 123200, 123300, 123400, 123500), 
    `2014` = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), `2015` = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), `2016` = c(2, 
    1, 1, 2, 1), `2017` = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1), `2018` = c(2, 3, 
    1, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Allan, thank you so much for your fast response. I tried your approach on the real dataset several times, but unfortunately I just got vectors containing NA's, like 'c(NA, NA, NA)'

Answer (score 1):

`matrixStats::rowDiffs` might be helpful and faster here.

```
z <- apply(matrixStats::rowDiffs(as.matrix(df[-1])) != 0, 1, which.max) + 1; d <- dim(df)
m <- matrix(t(df[-1])[c(z + 0:(d[2] - 2)*d[1] - 1, z + 0:(d[2] - 2)*d[1])],,2, di=list(c(), c('before', 'after')))
cbind(df, `[<-`(cbind(change=1, year=substring(names(df[-1])[z], 2), m), z == 2, 1:4, 0))
#       ID X2014 X2015 X2016 X2017 X2018 change year before after
# 1 123100     1     1     2     2     2      1 2016      1     2
# 2 123200     1     1     1     1     3      1 2018      1     3
# 3 123300     1     1     1     1     1      0    0      0     0
# 4 123400     2     2     2     2     2      0    0      0     0
# 5 123500     3     3     1     1     1      1 2016      3     1
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123100, 123200, 123300, 123400, 123500), 
    X2014 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), X2015 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), X2016 = c(2, 
    1, 1, 2, 1), X2017 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1), X2018 = c(2, 3, 1, 
    2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, but this unfortunately leads to an error message like: non-numeric argument for binary operator. Even though all columns of the data frame are numeric.

Comment: @Sam Weird, works fine for me; I exactly used the data you provided in OP. Just to be sure I included it now as `dput`.